# Generate Model, Controller outside of app folder in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

How to create controller and model files outside of app folder. For example, when we do

```
php artisan make:model ModelName
```

it creates Model file inside app folder. When we specify namespace like

```
php artisan make:model SomeFolder/ModelName
```

it creates Model file inside app/SomeFolder/ModelName.

I wanted to create model files outside of app folder. How to achieve this?

Comment: This is what you're looking for [Model out of app folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725760/how-to-make-controllers-models-views-outside-app-folder-in-lavarel-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the reason, but I managed to make it on my local computer by `php artisan make:model ../../mOdel` . Probably in production environment you won't be allowed to do this.

Comment: I'm developing an application where I have separated the logic, module wise. So, assume my folder name is Acme which is outside of app directory. Now, when I do php artisan make:model Sample, I want that model file to be placed under Acme/Model/Sample.php

Comment: php artisan make:model ../Acme/Model/Sample  ??

Comment: It worked, but I have small problem. My generated namespace is now like
App\..\Acme\Model. :(

Comment: change namespace manually after generation and do php artisan optimize or composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this via below steps:

1) Change `psr-4` value for 'App' into `composer.json` file

2) Run `composer dump-autoload` command for load composer

3) Run command for manually created model `php artisan make:model yourfoldername/model`

NOTE: Make sure, whenever you create model using command you need to change namespace.